# Python code with Chinese characters exec()

Tags: python

`exec(bytes('㵮湩⡴湩異⡴⤩瀊楲瑮嬨畳⡭慭⡰湩ⱴ瑳⡲⩮㈪⤩Ⱙ⩮㈪孝污⡬╮⁭潦⁲⁭湩爠湡敧㈨測⤩⥝','u16')[2:])`

What exactly does this do? On Codingame.com, people submit this Python code like this regularly.

My guess is that they've somehow broken down their Python code in such a way that these characters represent their code and executes it (which is a hacky way to win a "shortest mode" competition on the website).

Comment: You could see what this does by removing `exec`. I think you've already explained everything.

Comment: It is the coding problem. Check your encoding and decoding to see it is `utf-8`. If so, they may submit a text encoded in `gb18030` or `gb2312`, which would cause the strange characters like these.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm not really a Python programmer, the most I've done was use MicroPython when coding for raspberry pi, so I was hoping for some insight on how this was achieved and what exactly it does.

But thanks for confirming my guess on how it works!

Comment: @GeorgeY I see. So they encode their program to get those characters. Bytes then converts those characters back to regular code, and then exec runs that code. Sorry I was a bit slow, I've been meaning to learn more Python, but I just haven't gotten around to it.

Comment: The actual message in storage and in transmission are 0 and 1 s, 8 of them forms a byte, which entails 256 variations and is able to represent all European letters. But as for Chinese, there are hundreds of thousands of characters, so one byte is not enough. There comes encoding standard, some combine 2 bytes and some combine 3 bytes (utf-8) to represent one character, but the standard has to be declared and coherent (encode and decode in the same standard), otherwise you get mis-decoding like the strange characters above.

Comment: @GeorgeY I see, and the fact that it takes a bigger amount of data to store those characters is what allows the code's character length to be much smaller when converted to this form.

Comment: Because Windows always use gb2312  or gb18030 instead of utf-8 to save space, and because utf-8 was not even invented when Windows 98 was sold all over the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string of *chinese characters* is python code **encoded with UTF-8** and **decoded as UTF-16**.

### Decoded Python Code

```
 n=int(input())
 print([sum(map(int,str(n**2))),n**2][all(n%m for m in range(2,n))])
```

### Why?

You can cram the same information in less characters to get an edge on a '[code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)' competition where the char count matters

### How?

Here's some python code that generates that string:

```
>>> code = 'n=int(input())\nprint([sum(map(int,str(n**2))),n**2][all(n%m for m in range(2,n))])'
>>> print(code.encode('u8').decode('u16'))
㵮湩⡴湩異⡴⤩瀊楲瑮嬨畳⡭慭⡰湩ⱴ瑳⡲⩮㈪⤩Ⱙ⩮㈪孝污⡬╮⁭潦⁲⁭湩爠湡敧㈨測⤩⥝
```

Could be extended for any code:

```
>>> code = 'print(\'hello World!!\')'.encode('u8').decode('u16')
>>> print(code)
牰湩⡴栧汥潬圠牯摬℡⤧
```

### Test it

We can run this command to 'unpack' and execute:

```
>>> exec(bytes("牰湩⡴栧汥潬圠牯摬℡⤧","u16")[2:])
hello World!!
```